# "In search" vs "in searching"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, gerunds, grammaticality-in-context

> - Yesterday, I came out early of my home in ***search*** of my car's lost keys.
> - Yesterday, I came out early of my home in ***searching*** of my car's lost keys.

First, are both these sentences correct? Second, how could you chose whether to use gerund (searching) after preposition or noun (search)?

Answer (score 2):

They are not both correct.  **in searching of** is ungrammatical.

> Yesterday, I was in search of my keys.
>
> In searching for my keys, I found an old photograph.

In searching for = during, or as a result of, the act of searching for {something}

in search of = trying to find

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct.  The second is not.

Simplifying things a bit, gerunds like to be paired with the verb "to be."

> I am searching for my keys.
>
> I was searching for my keys yesterday.
>
> I will be searching for my keys when I'm done here.

Gerunds are generally not used in the construct "in [verb] of" without changing the "voice" of your statement.  But that's a question for another day.

Comment: In speaking of such things, you should exercise caution.

Comment: Because cryptic wizards might pass by.  Explaining your concern and choice to downvote would be more helpful to the OP.

Comment: Do you see any conflict between my comment above and the definitive statement with which you close your answer? In assuming of the questioner that he can read, I do him no disservice.

Comment: Fair enough.  I've edited the question.  Though no sane English speaker would use the phrase, "in assuming of."  It may be grammatically correct, but it sounds awful.  Since this is a site for people learning to speak English as a second language...

Comment: The gerund-participle is frequently and commonly used in the construction _in [verb] of._ This _particular_ verb doesn't take the preposition _of_ in this usage. The question of active or passive voice doesn't come into it.